# Modifying regression table from tab_model so that rows are grouped under title

Tags: r, sjplot

I would like to group rows of a regression table under a title. If not possible with this package, could you please recommend another one?

```
library(sjPlot)

data <- data.frame(id=1:6, a=rnorm(6, 5,2), b=rnorm(6,2,1), c=rnorm(6, 0,1), d=rnorm(6,3,2))

m <- lm(a~b+c+d, data)
tab_model(m)
```

[image]

Looking for this instead:

```
Predictors  Estimates     CI          p
(Intercept) -0.53   -36.45 – 35.39  0.955
b and c title
b            1.97   -9.61  – 13.54  0.541
c           -0.48   -4.87  – 3.91   0.683
d only title
d            0.36   -3.59  – 4.30   0.733
Observations    6
R2 / R2 adjusted    0.213 / -0.967
```